# Login in flutter without email password

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

So, I wanna make a flutter app where there will be login for 10-15 people and these people will  provide some sort of invitational code or token that other people need to put in textfield and then they can join the room of that person. I will do login for these 10-15 people with email authentication in firebase. So, please tell me how these people can generate invitational code or token for others to join them without any sort of id and pass.

Comment: Did you tried firebase anonymous login?

Comment: But that will simply log the user in, I want the user to enter code then only he can join

Answer (score 2):

try dynamic link with flutter and after link open then you can ask user to enter code and then if it is success then let the user in. [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)

Comment: Can you tell how can I create the code for login?

Comment: you need same invitation code for all the user and you can send it on link and user will get it via link

Comment: I appreciate your idea but i need different code for all users as based on that code they can access the data. I mean is there anything like dynamic codes..

Comment: I suggest you to generate code randomly and store it in firebase or any database and check everytime in database that is this code available and if it is already there then go for new random code generation this way you can send new code everytime.

Comment: Thnx Meet bro i too thought of it but while writing firebase rules how can i restrict the access.

Comment: firstly you can check that is code available in firebase and then based on that you can give condition to generate new code and when new code is generated then you will be able to share link , so that user can access that one .

Comment: But problem in this thing is how will i restrict the access while deploying security rules to firebase. Like if a person logs in via id pass then we can say req.auth!=null then allow read,write. But what about the rules when he enters by code.

Comment: Let you had share different code to different user and in database you have to manage code based on different documents. And on user side you fetch data and check is enter code is available then allow user to access else denied.

Comment: Ok will try it :)